# removing the punctuation in python

Tags: python, string

I would like to remove all punctuation in a text. To do so, I am using the following code:

```
import string
        
train_text_new = train_text
for text in range(len(train_text)):
  train_text_new[text].translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

The code is running, but the output is not like I expected, once it is not removing the punctuation.

```
train_text = ["TEXT!!! TEXT TEXT TEXT, TEXT", "TEXT? TEXT TEXT... TEXT TEXT"]
```

Expected output:

```
["TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT", "TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT"]
```

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: @M-Chen-3 My text without punctuation.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Your call to `translate` returns the string without punctuation but you throw it away.

Comment: Will you give a specific example showing the input and output?

Comment: `.translate(...)` returns a string. It does not modify the instance.

Comment: `str` objects in python are immutable and can not be changed. If you want to modify one you need to create another string that has the alterations you want.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

> Return a copy of the string...

It looks like you assume the string is modified in place.

Comment: train_wow = "TEXT!!! TEXT TEXT TEXT, TEXT"
train_wow.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) removes the punctuation. But it is not working in a for.

Comment: @Tazz It's working just fine. You are just ignoring the return value. Assign it to a variable to see the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use regex for this. But this might be a lot simpler than using the string library:

```
train_text = ["TEXT!!! TEXT TEXT TEXT, TEXT", "TEXT? TEXT TEXT... TEXT TEXT"]
train_text_new = ["".join([char for char in text if char.isalnum() or char == " "]) for text in train_text]
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to loop through each character in the text to be checked, and if it doesn't match any of the characters in the string of defined punctuation characters, it is appended to the output string.

```
    from string import punctuation as punctuation_string # Import just the part we need, and give it a handy name.
    output_string = '' # Set output to blank to start.
    for character in input_string: # For each character in the input string
        if character not in punctuation_string:
            output_string = output_string + character # Append the verified character to the output string.
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to remove all punctuations, in just one line of code is the following:

```
import string
train_text = ["TEXT!!! TEXT TEXT TEXT, TEXT", "TEXT? TEXT TEXT... TEXT TEXT"]
new_list = [''.join([x for x in text if x not in string.punctuation]) for text in train_text]
```

Basically what this does is, for every string in your list `train_text`, create a list made only by the characters in the string that are not in `string.puntuation` and then, with the .join method, it transforms the list (without the punctuation characters) back into a string.

Answer (score 0):

A regex fits nice fo this problem, use `"[^A-Za-z0-9 ]"` to express what you want to keep, uppercase, lowercase, digits and space and you're done

```
import re

train_text = ["TEXT!!! TEXT TEXT TEXT, TEXT", "TEXT? TEXT TEXT... TEXT TEXT"]
pattern = re.compile(r"[^A-Za-z0-9 ]")
train_text = [pattern.sub("", text) for text in train_text]
print(train_text)
```

The othe way by specifying the things to remove, maybe with `string.punctation`

```
import re
import string

train_text = ["TEXT!!! TEXT TEXT TEXT, TEXT", "TEXT? TEXT TEXT... TEXT TEXT"]
pattern = re.compile(r"[" + string.punctuation + "]")
train_text = [pattern.sub("", text) for text in train_text]
```